# How can I have python export my scraped variables as a .csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://mychesterfieldschools.com/mams/news-and-announcements/'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-sm-12 col-md-12')

for results in results:
    body = results.find('p')
    link = results.find('a')
    a = body.text
    b = link
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

The strings are *weird*, and I'm very new to Python. Please help! I've tried using Pandas but it didn't work for me.

Here is the desired output:
Chromebook for support for students is available as follows through July 30: Tuesdays at Thomas Dale HS from 8 – 10 am Thursdays at CTC@Hull from 2-4,
...Read Full Article

Here are some resources to keep your child engaged in Mathematics over the summer and prepare for the course they will enter in the fall. ALEKS – Your child has been using ALEKS during the school year in math class. ALEKS is an adaptive math program that provides each student with a personalized learning path […],
...Read Full Article

“Full STEAM Ahead is a conference by CodeVA dedicated to empowering young women through Science, Technology, Engineering, the Arts, and Mathematics. We inspire our students by connecting them with female role models in engaging hands-on workshops. Our speakers will share their experience as leaders in their respective industries, highlighting the importance of STEAM and the […],
...Read Full Article

As a result of the statewide closure of schools, Chesterfield County Public Schools is rescheduling opportunities for pre-kindergarten and kindergarten registration. Both in-person opportunities will be rescheduled when restrictions related to large gatherings are lifted or eased. In the meantime, there are opportunities for online registration for prospective prekindergarten and kindergarten students. The attached news release […],
...Read Full Article

Comment: does `csv` module help? https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Strings are not weird, those are HTML tags that you have requested and parsed. What output do you expect? How do you plan to convert something like anchor and paragraph tags/their content into a CSV?

Comment: @MatusDubrava I'm not quite sure? When the variables are printed they look how i want them to.

Comment: I see them but I don't understand how you want to convert those blobs of text into CSV. Not saying that it cannot be done it is just not immediately obvious because it can be done in many different ways. Maybe if you posted expected CSV output created by hand.

Comment: Added output in body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created 2 arrays to store 2 different types the scraped data.
`pandas.DataFrame()` will create a data frame object and `pandas.to_csv()` sends the dataframe object to a .csv file.

This may not be the most efficient code but it works

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://mychesterfieldschools.com/mams/news-and-announcements/'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-sm-12 col-md-12')

// declaring the 2 arrays for storing your scraped data
text = []
a_tags = []

for results in results:
    body = results.find('p')
    link = results.find('a')
    a = body.text
    b = link
    print(a)        // prints the text (data type string)
    print(b)        // prints the tag (data type bs4.element.Tag object)

    // store the text in text array
    text.append(a)

    // convert the tags to string and store in a_tags array
    a_tags.append(str(b))

// prints the saved arrays
print("text :    ", text)
print("tags :    ", a_tags)

// creates a pandas dataframe object of the above 2 arrays
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Text": text,
        "A_tags": a_tags
    }
)

// converts to csv
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

Links to documentation :
[`pandas.DataFrame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)
[`pandas.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Output `data.csv` file appears in the same directory as your python script.

This is how the csv looks on Microsoft Office Excel :
[image]